# How to map two entities to one database table by using Entity Framework (code first to an existing database)?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm

I got stuck with creating mapping for two entities that have to be mapped to the same database table. The reason why I need it is to create lite entity and full entity that will be used in different cases. I have already had existing database and I have my own database context that is derived from `DbContext` class. All mappings were made by using `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` classes.

The table.

```
[PROCESS]
ProcessId <int> PK
Name <nvarchar>
StartDate <datetime>
ProcessSequency <int>
Limit <int>
OwnerName <nvarchar>
```

Now this table is mapped to the single domain model, but I want to change it.
I want to split this entity to the next two.

```
public class ProcessEntity
{
    public int ProcessId { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ProcessDetailsEntity ProcessDetails { get; set; }
}

public class ProcessDetailsEntity
{
    public int ProcessId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public int ProcessSequency { get; set; }
    public int Limit { get; set; }
    public string OwnerName { get; set; }
    public virtual ProcessEntity ProcessBase { get;set; }
}
```

I created two configuration classes for them.

```
public class ProcessEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProcessEntity>
{
    public ProcessEntityConfiguration()
    {
        // ToTable("PROCESS");
        Map(m => m.ToTable("PROCESS"))
        HasKey(t => t.ProcessId);
        HasRequired(s => s.ProcessDetails).WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.ProcessBase);
    }
}

public class ProcessDetailsEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProcessDetailsEntity>
{
    public ProcessDetailsEntityConfiguration()
    {
        // ToTable("PROCESS");
        HasKey(t => t.ProcessId);
        Map(m => m.ToTable("PROCESS"));
    }
}
```

Everything looks fine and should work, but I see the error:

> "InnerException": {
>         "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>         "ExceptionMessage": "Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Discriminator'.",
>         "ExceptionType": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException",
>         "StackTrace": "   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

I googled it and found out that the `Discriminator` is used by Entity Framework in order to apply [TPH - Table per hierarchy](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) behavior. I also found one useful article that could be a solution for me: [Entity Framework - Advanced mapping scenarios](https://dotnetfalcon.com/stackoverflow-adventures-entity-framework-code-first-advanced-mapping-scenarios/). Unfortunately the solution that is provided under **Mapping a single table to multiple entities** header doesn't work for me and I don't know why. Could you help me with this issue?

I'm a little bit familiar with `NHibernate`, so I tried to do it in `NHibernate` way. The idea is to create two independent entities. It was my first approach. Here is the code of this attempt.

```
public abstract class ProcessBaseEntity
{
    public int ProcessId { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProcessEntity : ProcessBaseEntity
{
}

public class ProcessDetailsEntity : ProcessBaseEntity
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public int ProcessSequency { get; set; }
    public int Limit { get; set; }
    public string OwnerName { get; set; }
}

public class ProcessEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProcessEntity>
{
    public ProcessEntityConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("PROCESS");
        HasKey(t => t.ProcessId);
    }
}

public class ProcessDetailsEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProcessDetailsEntity>
{
    public ProcessDetailsEntityConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("PROCESS");
        HasKey(t => t.ProcessId);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this attempt wasn't successful. The following exception was thrown:

> The entity types 'ProcessEntity' and 'ProcessDetailsEntity' cannot
>   share table 'PROCESS' because they are not in the same type hierarchy
>   or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with
>   matching primary keys between them.

I started splitting my first entity into two small as I want to make my SQL query as lighter as possible. Sometimes I wonder if it essential or not? Maybe my request won't be lighter even I spitted my entity. Maybe it worth trying to put all my properties in a single entity and forget about it.

Comment: Did you try to delete `virtual` for your properties?

Comment: Not sure what your goal is, but if it is to work with a smaller subset of fields/properties, then I would suggest ViewModels as a better alternative.

Comment: @SteveGreene It's a good way as well, but I am interested in making light SQL query. So you will fetch less columns. I believe that it will be better than fetching all properties and use only two of them.

Comment: You can add a select clause to your LINQ so you only fetch needed columns. See [this](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/09/select-specific-columns-entity-framework-query/).